# cellForRowAtIndexPath is called when there is no row

Tags: objective-c

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([BGSearchParameter defaultSearchParameters].fetchedResults.count==0)
    {
        PO(@([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]));
        PO(@([self tableView:nil numberOfRowsInSection:0]));
        PO(@(indexPath.row));
        while (false);
    }
```

This is the result

```
self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]): 20
 @([self tableView:nil numberOfRowsInSection:0]): 0
```

Now, I do not know who call that `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

The debuggin windows shows that the main thread somehow call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I usually fix this issue by returning some random `UITableViewCell` that's never displayed. Howerver, I think it's a bug.

What functions can call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` anyway besides tableReload and why it doesn't call

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

first?

It seems that my tableView still think there are 20 rows even though there are only 0 rows.

Comment: Are there any other UITableViews in the controller? Or is there any possibility that there are other controllers with UITableViews that delegate to that controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be your tableview is not refreshing. Please include this line in your code so that it will refersh each time:-

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I think I change the array under the TableView and then didn't do reloadData. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter "tableView" of this method to check whether the right instance of "UITableView" is called. For example, in the delegate method" - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section" add these code:

```
if(tableView== youwanttocheckTableView) {
//do what you want to do
}
```

You can also check which TableView instance have set its delegate equals "self" in this class.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem.